# How to calculate percentile

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

When you have a list of numbers

```
[1, 3,5, 7, 7, 9, 11, 11, 11, 24]
```

I want a list of percentiles

```
[10%,20%,30%, 40%, 40%, 60%, 70%, 70% 70%, 100%]
```

In plain python code,

```
percentiles = []

prev_value = None
prev_index = None
for value, index in enumerate(l):
   index_to_use = index + 1
   if prev_value == value:
       index_to_use = prev_index
  
   percentile = index_to_use / len(l) * 100
   percentiles.apend(percentile)

   if value != prev_value:
       prev_value = value
       prev_index = index
```

Can you do this simpler with numpy?

Comment: your python code does not produce the right result: `[20.0, 40.0, 60.0, 80.0, 80.0, 100.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 250.0]`

Comment: actually, its not very clear what you want.  Can you specify exaclty what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Cute Numpy Trick

```
mylist = [1, 3, 5, 7, 7, 9, 11, 11, 11, 24]
unique_values, index, inverse = np.unique(mylist, return_index=True, return_inverse=True)
(index[inverse] + 1) / len(inverse) * 100

array([ 10.,  20.,  30.,  40.,  40.,  60.,  70.,  70.,  70., 100.])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use np.percentile as follows:

```
import numpy as np
if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = [1, 3,5, 7, 7, 9, 11, 11, 11, 24]
    percentiles = np.percentile(data, np.arange(10, 110, 10))
    print(percentiles)
```

Result:

```
[ 2.8  4.6  6.4  7.   8.   9.8 11.  11.  12.3 24. ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this:

```
In [501]: arr = np.array([1, 3,5, 7, 7, 9, 11, 11, 11, 24])
In [504]: l = (arr - 1) / (np.max(arr) - 1) * 100

In [505]: l
Out[505]: 
array([  0.        ,   8.69565217,  17.39130435,  26.08695652,
        26.08695652,  34.7826087 ,  43.47826087,  43.47826087,
        43.47826087, 100.        ])
```